# Oracle CREATE TABLE missing right parenthesis WHY?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Using Oracle I am trying to create these tables (this is just one) and I keep getting the "missing right parenthesis" error. I cannot understand why.

It's not the server, tried a premade table and it worked fine.
 Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
Proj_Num DECIMAL(2,0)
Proj_Name CHAR(40),
Proj_Value DECIMAL(10,2),
Proj_Balance DECIMAL(10,2),
Emp_Num CHAR(3) 
FOREIGN KEY (emp_num),
PRIMARY KEY (Proj_Num) )
;
```

Comment: I'm almost 100% certain that you want `varchar(40)` instead of `char(40)`. And the employee number should probably be `number` instead of `char(3)`

Comment: Thank you, horse. I really appreciate your input! I will apply the changes and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a comma after the first field:

```
Proj_Num DECIMAL(2,0), <--- No comma here in your example
Proj_Name CHAR(40),
```

Comment: Ok, so that took care of the parenthesis error. Now it's giving me "missing or invalid option for that line.    Proj_Num DECIMAL(2,0),

Comment: @rikeerik: your foreign key definition is wrong. Please read the manual for the correct syntax.